# Accessing turtle-on patch-ahead internal variables

Tags: netlogo

```
ifelse any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 with isgeneral = 1 or any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 90 1 with isgeneral = 1
[
 fd -2
 set energy energy -2
]
[
 fight
]
```

This is the idea of what I want to do but have not been able to , it gives me

> WITH expected this input to be an agentset, but got a number instead

and highlights the 1 from 'patch-ahead 1'.

isgeneral is a turtles-own variable how would I go about doing this ?

In case it wasn't clear I want to check if there's a turtle ahead or to the right and if that turtle has 'isgeneral' variable set to 1

Answer (score 4):

A couple things. It's parsing:

```
any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 with isgeneral = 1
```

as

```
any? turtles-on patch-ahead (1 with isgeneral = 1)
```

You need to add parentheses to make it have the `with` act on the turtles. Next, the `isgeneral = 1` is something you're having the turtles check (as you point out). In technical terms, `with` takes a reporter block that it then passes to the agents in the agentset for evaluation. Blocks are surrounded by `[]`. So the corrected code is:

```
any? (turtles-on patch-ahead 1) with [ isgeneral = 1 ]
```

The part after the `or` needs analagous changes.

Hope that helps!